# How to use snoowrap with javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, reddit

I have been trying to use snoop wrap with javascript to be able to call the reddit api, and I continously get an error here:

```
const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');
```

The error says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I have found multiple different answers where they use browserify, but I have tried that too, to no avail. Can someone please give me a straight answer about what I have to do to solve this error?

Comment: I think you will find this useful [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: No I have already tried those, and they don't work for me

Comment: How are you running the file? With `node file.js` or something else?

Comment: Also, is this on the client side or server side?

Comment: Hi I found the solution and posted it already

Comment: If you've found the solution and posted an answer, then accept it.

Comment: I posted the answer, but I have to wait 24 hours to accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was just a problem on my part because I included my javascript files like so when using broser:

```html
<script src="originalfile.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

When I should have done it like this:

```html
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```